# iOS -Chart: Y- Axis interval difference between value

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I want to make Y-axis interval with a certain difference. Let's say the multiple of 100 or any fix value, currently it draws with their own interval.

I am sharing my formatting code here.

```
 let leftAxis = chartView.leftAxis
 leftAxis.valueFormatter = IntAxisValueFormatter()
 leftAxis.granularityEnabled = true
 leftAxis.granularity = 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve my challenge, I am adding my fix here. First I calculated the total range then divided them by interval diff and set the **LabelCount**.

```
let totalRange = maxY - minY
let interval = 100 //Let's say 100 in my case
leftAxis.setLabelCount(Int(totalRange/interval) + 1, force: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is you calculate scale value according to your data. And you can use following function to scale as you need. But exact with value difference I don't think it is possible.

```
self.lineChart.setScaleMinima(1.0, scaleY: 2.0)
```

In above value first parameter will zoom in horizontally while second will zoom vertically.

Comment: thanks for your input but I managed to fix my problem by setting LabelCount for Y-axis. I am sharing my fix here as well.


let totalRange = maxY - minY
let interval = 100 //Let's say 100 in my case
leftAxis.setLabelCount(Int(totalRange/interval) + 1, force: true)